# How make audio to start from the specified point in the video and last specified amount of time

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, audio-processing

Lets say I have sample video named `"samplevideo"` and sample audio named `"sampleaudio"`. I want to replace the audio of the samplevideo with the sampleaudio starting from 5 sec to 12 sec. Until 5 sec mark the video audio won't change, then sampleaudio starts and lasts for 7 sec.

I tried to come up with ffmpeg command that solves this problem:

```
ffmpeg -i samplevideo.mp4  -i sampleaudio.aac -ss 20 -map 0:v  -map 1:a -c:v copy output.mp4
```

**Problem:** 
It cuts video starting from 20 sec time mark. What I want is to persist the video and the original audio stream until it hits desired time mark and then use sampleaudio until desired end time.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use amix with selective muting.

```
ffmpeg -i samplevideo.mp4  -i sampleaudio.aac \
       -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0:enable=between(t\,5\,12)[a0];\
                        [1:a]atrim=0:7,adelay=5s:all=1[a1];\
                        [a0][a1]amix=normalize=0:duration=first[aout]"
       -map 0:v  -map [aout] -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Use ffmpeg 5.0

Answer (score 0):

From [problem research](https://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg+add+audio+to+video+at+specific+time), Looking at: 
https://superuser.com/questions/708125/add-audio-at-specific-time-in-video-using-ffmpeg

You could try as:

```
ffmpeg -i samplevideo.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:20 -i sampleaudio.aac -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -async 1 output.mp4
```

If still not working, then check the other suggestions from the research results.

Comment: The command you provided mutes the audio of the video until specified offset. I want audio unchanged. I am trying other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to splice audio using filtergraph. Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i samplevideo.mp4  -i sampleaudio.aac \
       -filter_complex "[1:a]asendcmd='5.0 astreamselect map 1;\
                                      12.0 astreamselect map 0',\
                        [0:a]astreamselect=inputs=2:map=0[aout]"
       -map 0:v  -map [aout] -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Changed -filter_graph to -filter. Got this error: [error](https://pastebin.com/1SUXEQc6).

Comment: sorry, should read `filter_complex`. `-filter` only works if you have only 1 input and 1 output.

Comment: I tried it with filter_complex as you said. But didn't get the expected result. Output video audio gets muted after 5 sec and lasts till the end. Expected result: sampleaudio should be heard after 5 sec untill 12 sec. Here is [log](https://pastebin.com/9aLCQsZd) If you need, link to the input and output files provided in logs link.

Comment: OK, so `START-END` syntax in documentation doesn't work, try the edited version where 2 commands are now issued.